# Adding only one entry to toctree for subdirectory

Tags: python-sphinx, myst

The toctree in the `index.html` page is one level deep when I expect it to be two levels deep.

The project directory structure is like this:

```
index.md
dlg.md
dlg/about/index.md
dlg/...
```

The `dlg.md` page looks like this (in MyST syntax):

````
```{toctree}
:maxdepth: 1
dlg/about/index
dlg/advanced/index
dlg/advanced_filter/index
... (more entries)

```

# Dialogs page
````

The `dlg.html` page is rendered like this as expected.

[image]

The `index.md` page looks like this. Note that I tried using `maxdepth` to fix my issue.:

````
```{toctree}
:maxdepth: 1
dlg

```
````

`index.html` is rendered like this:

[image]

Note how the `Dialogs page` entry is the last entry in the toctree, and that all entries are on one level. I was expecting the toctree to look like this:

```
- Dialogs page
    - About EmEditor dialog box
    - ...
```

Therefore I thought that using `:maxdepth: 1` would only show `Dialogs page` and hide the rest. How do I make it so that only `Dialogs page` is shown in the table of contents for `index.html`?

Comment: `dlg.md` at the root is a strange document structure. Try moving it to `dlg/index.md`.

Comment: @StevePiercy I tried that too with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by rearranging the title. I moved the `# Dialogs page` line to the top of the page, before the `toctree`. Now the `dlg.md` file looks like:

````
# Dialogs page

```{toctree}
:maxdepth: 1
dlg/about/index
dlg/advanced/index
dlg/advanced_filter/index
... (more entries)

```
````

Now the `index.html` page looks as I originally wanted it to.